# How to diagram a sentence containing a sentence adverb?

Tags: syntax-trees, generative-grammar, grammar-formalism, descriptive-linguistics

There is a traditional representation of a sentence's parts and it's relation called Kellogs-Reeds diagramming method,which is not used in linguistics.
There are also linguistic representations like phrase structure grammars.

How do you diagram the following sentence using both methods,the pedagogical and the linguistic depiction:

> Evidently,the American campus has become a hatchery for insanity.

Comment: What a syntax tree for a particular sentence looks like is entirely dependent on what particular theory you are using. For this reason, our [Help Center](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rules out general syntax tree requests as off-topic on this site.

Comment: In general, a sentence adverb would usually be placed as an adjunct to the root of the sentence (e.g. IP or CP).

Comment: The phrase structure grammar that is used as a de facto universal to exemplify syntax trees as used in wikipedia . As for the Kellogs-Reeds diagramming ,there is only one.

Comment: Such a de facto universal phrase structure grammar doesn't exist.

Comment: "Evidently" is a supplementary adjunct, more specifically a "speech act-related" adjunct. Supplements don't modify another element; instead they have an "anchor" to which they relate. In your example, the anchor is the entire clause _the American campus has become a hatchery for insanity_. I could give you a conventional tree diagram, but I wouldn't touch the Reed-Kellogg system with  a barge pole!

Comment: As a sentence adverb, _Evidently_ would go on an elevated horizontal line above the VP _has become_; the  platform itself would be connected to a dashed vertical line rising between _has_ and _become_ (and having a split fork at the bottom, in certain versions -- there's far more than one; sorry). It works almost as well as making the adverb a higher predicate. Of course, this is the same way one would also diagram _has evidently become_, except that _evidently_ wouldn't be capitalized in that case.

Comment: Like pseudocode when exemplifying a certain programming language paradigm. Which phrase structure grammar is the one which divides at the top the sentence into NP and VP,than PP  and finally goes down to terminal categories like v,det,adj,n ?

Comment: @billj thx for mentioning the supplementary adjunct. Which of the plethora of psg are you referring to?

Comment: I've posted an answer with a tree diagram. It is simplified down to the bare bones, but it does show the relationship of the supplement to its anchor. In this particular example the supplement has the entire clause as anchor, as shown by the broken line leading from the functional label 'Supplement' to the category label 'Clause'.

Comment: In McCawley's system (in *TSPE*), since *evidently* is a sentence adverb, which makes it a sentence modifier, it and the sentence it modifies would be constituents of a sentence.  That is, the adverb would be Chomsky-adjoined to the rest of the sentence.  However, agreeing with @BillJ that *evidently* is a speech act oriented verb, I think it is a constituent of a root sentence, which is why it is unembedable.   This can't be described in McCawley's system, but it can in mine, where a root S is a S0 and an adverb that can only go in a root sentence is an Adv0, where the 0 means at the top.

Comment: McCawley could just hang _Evidently_ independently from a 0' ('zero-bar': constituent whose head is no part of speech), which is also useful for vocatives and other simultaneous speech acts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified Tree Diagram of Supplementary Adjunct:

[image]